# antiSMASH download_databases.py error in subprocess call

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to intall antiSMASH on my research group's server but hitting an issue with the final stage of downloading the relevant databases. The makers provide a script "download_databases.py" to do this for you (see code at https://bitbucket.org/antismash/antismash/src/718da23d059742048bf044a1ed663806051eb0b2/download_databases.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default).
Sadly there seems to be some kind of access issue (I'm not root and sudo doesn't help).

Server is RedHat CentOS 7.2.1511

Command run is "python download_databases.py" in antismash directory. Output is below:

```
Creating checksum of Pfam-A.hmm.gz
Extraction of Pfam-A.hmm.gz finished successfully.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "download_databases.py", line 221, in <module>
    main()
  File "download_databases.py", line 198, in main
    compile_pfam(filename)
  File "download_databases.py", line 161, in compile_pfam
    execute(command)
  File "download_databases.py", line 51, in execute
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Does anyone with experience of this have an idea of what I need to do? I've tried a local install of Python (2.7) where I have read/write access but that doesn't seem to help as the script is still looking elsewhere for the subprocess script (my own install is at the top of the PATH). Do I possibly need to install something extra with the local install or customise the install locations to include the subprocess etc stuff?

Thanks in advance. I'm no expert and really appreciate the help.

EDIT: Well I feel quite stupid now. Thanks to Hannu for suggesting I check $PATH and what binary the script was trying to execute. It turned out to be one of antiSMASH's dependencies (hmmpress) which I hadn't yet added to the $PATH on this machine. It hadn't occurred to me that it would be required prior to actually running antiSMASH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `print commands` or something like that to your execute function and see what it tries to execute.  The only explanation to get the error in that command is that the script or binary it tries to execute cannot be found.

Try adding a full path to your binary. That alone might solve the issue. Check that there are no typos in the command. Remember `commands` needs to be a list if it contains parameters, for example ["/usr/bin/foo/myprogram", "-a", "42", "-b", "/tmp/outputfile"] or whatever it is you need to pass to the program.